# Saving File and Opening with Android App

Tags: android, mime-types, file-extension, file-association, file-browser

I am saving a binary to a file with a custom extension for instance .custom. How do I save it to a specific mime type? I want my app to be called to open that custom file. In the manifest I used */* as mimeType but the app gets called even when tapping an image. I used octet-stream but the file doesn't get recognized and the app does not get opened. I just want to save a binary with custom extension and the OS would call my app when it encounters this file.

```
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="file" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.test" />
        <data android:host="*" />
   </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after several views only without answers I figured it out. The post on this link helped me resolve my issue.

https://publish.illinois.edu/weiyang-david/2013/04/11/how-to-write-intent-filter-dealing-with-mime-type-problem/

This example was it

```
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:host="*" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\.pdf" />
  </intent-filter>
```

I replaced the scheme to "file" and replaced with my pathPattern. Removing the mimeType was key to solving my issue. File browsers now suggests to open the custom file with my app.